# how to compute the 4-D cell plot against SNR?

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array C of size `(10 21 1000 21)`. I can use `cell2mat` or `Cmeans` to convert the cell C to a double or numeric value. Given that I have an SNR OF size `(1 21)`, how do I plot a graph of SNR against C. Matlab keep giving me error saying `"data may not have more than 2 dimensions"` when I do `plot(SNR,C)` but gives a straight line for `plot(SNR,Cmeans(9,:,1000,21))`.

Comment: What does it mean to plot a 4D array?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, I am referring to how to use the cell array of 4-dimensions to plot against an SNR say [0:20] AND not a 4-D array plot

Comment: I figured it out. Will post the solution in a short while.